# OpenWRT via static ethernet address

Tags: networking, dns, ethernet, openwrt, ip-address

I can't get my [Onion Omega2](https://onion.io/store/omega2/), which runs OpenWRT, to connect to my ethernet via a static IP address and two DNS addresses. To connect my PC, I have to set the following:
IP address: `82.149.xxx.xxx`
subnet mask: `255.255.255.0`
gateway: `82.149.xxx.xxx`
DNS server: `212.xxx.xxx.xxx`, `83.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Which settings have to be made in `/etc/config/network` and possibly elsewhere?

I tried the following without success:

```
config interface 'wan'                
    option proto 'static'         
    option ifname 'eth0'       
    option ipaddr '82.149.xxx.xxx'  
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option gateway '82.149.xxx.xxx'  
    list dns '83.xxx.xxx.xxx'    
    list dns '212.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

Comment: Do you mean that you enter the public static IP information in your PC instead of your router?  There are a few things that don't seem right.  An `Ethernet address` would not be an IP but a MAC address.  I also doubt that you are assigned a /24 network so your `netmask` is apparently wrong.  Also consider clarifying what it means to do something without success.  Does it mean that the router does not accept your configuration or that your PC has no Internet access?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you right here. At my PC, I have to set these configurations to connect to the internet via ethernet (provided by my student's appartement). Nothing about an ethernet address I guess. When I try to transfer these settings to the Onion Omega2 by setting the `wan` interface in the `network` file, it doesn't connect to the internet (no successful `ping`). Don't know what you mean about a /24 network, but the netmask address is definitely `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: Is your PC the Omega2 or the Omega2 is your router?  If it is the router, can you log on to it to check if it has network access?  Your setup is unclear and I would have a ton of things to ask to troubleshoot an issue that I'd solve in 5 minutes if I was there.  Try to give clarifications.  I'm not sure if your problem is with your computer's NIC configuration, with DHCP, with the Omega2's routing configuration, with DNS configuration or whatever.

Comment: I solved the problem but try to give more information about the Omega2 here. It's a single board computer that can act as a router for a wifi connection. That's why it needs access to the internet via ethernet. Running OpenWRT, it can be configured as a router as any other OpenWRT router. The key problem was that I couldn't use a DHCP connection but had to set the mentioned settings, which was not explained by the Onion Omega help.

Answer (score 1):

The given settings in `/etc/config/network` are correct. However, to apply the settings, it isn't sufficient to restart the network via `/etc/init.d/network restart` but also applying the DNS servers via `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart` which had not been done. After that, the Onion Omega2 is able to connect to the internet via its ethernet connection.